# 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, hosting

Tengo una página que está en un hosting compartido (000WebHost) que hasta ayer funcionaba perfectamente (funciona hace varios meses). No cambie absolutamente nada, pero de repente dejó de funcionar, ahora solo se queda cargando y jamás termina de hacerlo.
Es un proyecto que funciona mediante bases de datos con PHP, pero según las estadisticas de 000webhostapp no rebasé ningún limite.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización:**

Después de una larga espera apareció este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error 502 es más común de lo que parece, y desde luego el hoting que mencionas puede presentar este tipo de error.

**¿Qué significa 502 Bad Gateway?**

Las aplicaciones web modernas incluyento tu sitio web en php están alojadas en varios servidores.
Ahora, cuando abres tu sitio de WordPress en su navegador, desencadena múltiples solicitudes de todas las partes que se unen para generar la página que ve en la ventana de su navegador.

Estas solicitudes se envían al servidor proxy inverso, que determina dónde enviar las solicitudes. El servidor proxy inverso luego recupera:

- PHP y otro contenido dinámico del servidor de aplicaciones.
- Sus bases de datos MySQL desde el servidor de la base de datos.
- Imágenes, JavaScript, CSS, temas, complementos y otros archivos del
  servidor web.
  [image: 502]

Ten en cuenta que los servidores que se encuentran detrás del servidor proxy inverso se conocen como servidores de origen o upstream .

Pero, ¿dónde está nuestro error 502 en todo esto? Se produce un error 502 Bad Gate Way cuando el servidor proxy inverso recibe una respuesta no válida de cualquiera de los servidores de upstream.

**Corregir error 502:**

- Regarcar URL.
- Borra la cache de tu navegador, muchas  veces archivos obsoletos que
  tienes
- almacenados en local  pueden provocar que se genere una respuesta
- Reiniciar tu modem/router es  otra posible solución.
- Borrar caché del DNS local, desde windows  abrir CMD y ejecutar el
  comando: ipconfig /flushdns